# What's the field before ssh-rsa in known_hosts on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Tags: ssh

`ssh-gen` by default creates a public key like

`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E...6OEBTVwLRP1Ocyr user@DESKTOP-8BL3U5O`

The Raspbian 9 has a different format

`|1|dMpV8+ILjAAD11mhp57Q7hVk/4A=|pvCuzPyguQCwV9cN908uBz6CZLE= ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2E...6OEBTVwLRP1Ocyr`

What is the field before `ssh-rsa`? How to generate it so `id_rsa.pub` can be inserted into `known_hosts`?

Comment: What is the exact command you're using? I use 'ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -C mykey' and the resulting ssh key doesn't have anything funky like you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ssh-gen by default creates a public key like

I think you mean `ssh-keygen` but yes.

> The Raspbian 9 has a different format...

Nope, it has the same format.  And the same format for the `known_hosts` file, which is where `|1|dMpV8+ILjAAD11mhp57Q7hVk/4A=|pvCu...` came from.

That file does not have the same purpose as `authorized_keys`.

Just to make sure we are one the same page:

```
> cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
> ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): here
[...]
> cat here.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC38zEm02Z4HpSd/wnWf58wtwNMct6uAztr99RpvSaiFdqq9x8zmXuqk79A+zorfqIyGdmv8kHTjAFRrhNVdz5wYstDTbxjT8hd/GAWvkoi+/plX6mEvEho9Z7etcwv6xu/iuZHXhXr/NN1SVWl2UgwhrK/QkM+bADPTKHm/mks/aJZusqn+LDbyDaDLIMFNfSxmikmKmUvYXnCULnFGsV7KevCI8spwh0zs+aJDGml0Ib5Fwa0fvyuI9fdY3mc0IU3EBiqS45eJeMd0aB77JytoWpwOlUopGYI+CkuF4J+Voj8Z1f4tWWI0znss6wh2pgz5sm5+cii3VHCSYdbU6Xn user@three.house

> cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
|1|VX1e6UnkWMoOywd7lCacvJ1wAw4=|V8ofy+...
```

According to `man sshd`, a `known_hosts` file can have a number of formats but I think that is the one auto-generated by the client when you say "yes" to adding a host.

Comment: Forgot to mention why i want to do this. I was trying to setup passwordless login. I should look at authorized_keys instead of known_hosts.
Thanks for the answer. It's spot on.

Comment: `known_hosts` (unlike `id_x.pub` and `authorized_keys`) always has a first field containing the host name and/or address, but the format posted is specifically the _hashed_ host format used by `ssh` with option `HashKnownHosts=yes` and `ssh-keygen -H` and `ssh-keyscan -H`